# Order of operators on subtract

Tags: printing, lua-table, subtraction, operations

```
print(table.getn(szExtension_Locations) - (g_nNumTeleportEntries - 1));
print(table.getn(szExtension_Locations) - g_nNumTeleportEntries - 1);
```

Output:

```
125
123
```

Why do these two lines of code produce a different result? Nothing is happening to the variables in between. The code is in that exact order. Even if I swap them, they still produce 123 then 125.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation are your parentheses:
Your first expression evaluates to:

```
a - (b - 1) = a - b + 1
```

while your second expression evaluates to:

```
a - b - 1
```

Thus you see the difference of 2.

This calculation is completely unrelated to [Lua](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lua_Programming/Expressions#Operator_precedence):

> Operator precedence works the same way in Lua as it typically does in mathematics. [...] Parentheses can be used to arbitrarily change the order in which operations should be executed.

More details about the minus sign before the parentheses can be found [here.](https://mathchat.me/2010/09/16/common-algebra-mistake-interpreting-negative-signs-in-front-of-parentheses/)

Comment: This looks correct, but could you elaborate more on the top equation?  Why does removing parentheses change the equation like this?

Comment: @soulzek the reason for the difference is the minus sign before the parentheses. Please check the links in my answer

Comment: @Steven Nevermind, LUA is resolving it left-to-right without parentheses. Subtract is a noncommutative mathematical operation where as + is, hence the confusion in my brain. This is what the code turns into:
first line:  5-(3-1) = 2
second line: (5-3)-1 = 1